# how to read from text file and store in matrix in c

Tags: c, text, matrix

the first to say is that I'm totally new to coding, so plz forgive my mistakes.
I'm now trying to read from a txt file which is rather large, it has about 1000000 lines and 4 cols

```
56.154 59.365 98.3333 20.11125
98.54 69.3645 52.3333 69.876
76.154 29.365 34.3333 75.114
37.154 57.365 7.0 24.768
........
........
```

I want to read them all and store them into a matrix, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  int j;

/*matrix*/
int** mat=malloc(1000000*sizeof(int));
for(i=0;i<1000000;++i)
mat[i]=malloc(4*sizeof(int));


  FILE *file;
  file=fopen("12345.txt", "r");

 for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
      for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
      {
       if (!fscanf(file, " %c", &mat[i][j])) 
           break;
       mat[i][j] -= '0'; /* I found it from internet but it doesn't work*/
       printf("\n",mat[i][j]);
      }

  }
  fclose(file);
}
```

The result is that I got nothing in my matrix. I hope u can help. Thanks in advance for any help.

---

Comment: I am sure that you will get an answer soon, but my advice would be: Learn to **debug**. Use a debugger, single-step through your program. Inspect the variables and check if they contain what you expect. Then you will soon be able to solve such a problem yourself.

Comment: ... and of course: read the **documentation**. Hint: What is the `%c` format in fscanf() for?

Comment: You don't need to include `malloc.h`, `malloc` is already included in `stdlib.h`

Comment: The problems are numerous. rooooookie, you should break this down into the simplest pieces and get it working from there. E.g. get array access/mallocing figured first, then, work on reading a single value from a file into the appropriate variable (float).

Comment: @MartinR  Thanks for ur advise, actually I read a lot documentation like <The C programming language> and some tutorials but I can't really remember when I write my code. And I will learn to debug, that sounds practical.

Comment: @AlterMann I tried but it doesn't work at first. But I wonder for an extra command, will it change my code or make my program slower? Thanks.

Comment: @Macattack  I agree with you, I'm starting to learn how to do self-correcting. There's a lot of things to learn, I have to go through them one by one. Thanks for ur advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many Issues, consider following, and of course see comments

```
int main()
{
  int i;
  int j;

/*matrix*/
/*Use double , you have floating numbers not int*/

double** mat=malloc(1000000*sizeof(double*)); 
for(i=0;i<1000000;++i)
mat[i]=malloc(4*sizeof(double));


  FILE *file;
  file=fopen("1234.txt", "r");

 for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
      for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
      {
  //Use lf format specifier, %c is for character
       if (!fscanf(file, "%lf", &mat[i][j])) 
           break;
      // mat[i][j] -= '0'; 
       printf("%lf\n",mat[i][j]); //Use lf format specifier, \n is for new line
      }

  }
  fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well, now I will go back to read carefully the basic conceptions.

Answer (score 1):

1. `fscanf( "%c", ... )` only scans one single character (e.g. '5'). By subtracting '0' you get the integer value `5` from the character `'5'`. You can use `"%d"` to scan integers that consist only of digits (not including formatting characters), or `"%f"` for floats (not sure if `56.154` is to be read as "56 thousand 154" (continental europe) or "56 plus 154/1000" (GB / USA) (the rest of the world: don't be offended I just don't know)
2. `printf( "\n", ... )`: you forgot to use any formatting string such as `%d` (int), `%f` (float) ... So your parameter will not be printed, just the newline itself.
3. `int** mat=malloc(1000000*sizeof(int));` You're allocating an array of `int *` here, so it should be `int** mat=malloc(1000000*sizeof(int *));`

**Edit:** I've looked again at your text file and have seen numbers like 98.54 that can't be formatted integers. So it's quite clear you will need `float` or `double` instead if `int` for your array and use `"%f"` for `float` or `"%lf"` for `double` in both `fscanf()` and `printf()`

Comment: It's very kind of you to explain everything to me, thanks very much. Now all the problem is clear to me, I know what to do for the next, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of things wrong with your code here.

First off you create a matrix of `int` yet you are reading in float values it looks like.  You probably want to use `double`

Second, when you are reading a double you should use

```
fscanf(file, "%lf", &some_double);  // fscanf(file, "%d", &some_int); for integers
```

Also when you are allocating your matrix, your first `malloc` you should pass

```
sizeof(double *) // or int * if you are really trying to use integers
```

Finally your line that does:

```
mat[i][j] -= '0'
```

What are you trying to accomplish here?  You're taking the int that you (tried) to read in and subtracting off '0'...

**Edit**  I also notice that you are hard coding the number of lines you are reading, I wouldn't do that unless you know the format of the file.

Comment: Actually all my problems are mentioned...... I thought it really hard to make all basic things clear to me, I will try harder, thanks!